# Convert Letters to Numbers with space

Tags: javascript, html, dom, numbers, character

Hi i will be using multiple sequences so i used this method. Right now it gets the appropriate number for the letters and i can type words and it sums the letters but i get NaN when using space. How can i make it possible to type words with spaces without getting NaN?

```
<html>
<body>
Word: <input type="text" name="fname" id="txt" value="Type a word..."><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>

function myFunction() {
var alphabet = {
a: 1, b: 2,
c: 3, d: 4,
e: 5, f: 6,
g: 7, h: 8,
i: 9, j: 10,
k: 11, l: 12,
m: 13, n: 14,
o: 15, p: 16,
q: 17, r: 18,
s: 19, t: 20,
u: 21, v: 22,
w: 23, x: 24,
y: 25, z: 26 
}
var str = document.getElementById("txt").value;
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
total += alphabet[str[i]];
alert(total);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
}
```

Comment: What do you want instead of `NaN`? Do you want to keep the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `' '` (space key) to your alphabet map and give it a value of `0`.

```js
function myFunction() {
var alphabet = {
a: 1, b: 2,
c: 3, d: 4,
e: 5, f: 6,
g: 7, h: 8,
i: 9, j: 10,
k: 11, l: 12,
m: 13, n: 14,
o: 15, p: 16,
q: 17, r: 18,
s: 19, t: 20,
u: 21, v: 22,
w: 23, x: 24,
y: 25, z: 26,
' ': 0
};
var str = document.getElementById("txt").value;
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
total += alphabet[str[i]];
alert(total);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
Word: <input type="text" name="fname" id="txt" value="Type a word..."><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Map a value for `' '` in your `alphabet` object:

```
var alphabet = {
    a: 1, b: 2,
    c: 3, d: 4,
    e: 5, f: 6,
    g: 7, h: 8,
    i: 9, j: 10,
    k: 11, l: 12,
    m: 13, n: 14,
    o: 15, p: 16,
    q: 17, r: 18,
    s: 19, t: 20,
    u: 21, v: 22,
    w: 23, x: 24,
    y: 25, z: 26,
    ' ': 42 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a zero as default value for not defined letters, like space or other characters.

This works with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), which test the first operand and if it is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), like `undefined` or zero or empty space `''` (as some others), it take the other operand (in this case zero) as value for adding to `total`.

```
total += alphabet[str[i]] || 0;
//                        ^^^^
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var alphabet = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8, i: 9, j: 10, k: 11, l: 12, m: 13, n: 14, o: 15, p: 16, q: 17, r: 18, s: 19, t: 20, u: 21, v: 22, w: 23, x: 24, y: 25, z: 26 },
        str = document.getElementById("txt").value,
        total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        total += alphabet[str[i]] || 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
Word: <input type="text" name="fname" id="txt" placeholder="Type a word..."><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```